# How to spell the word 'trie'?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

In computer science, there is a word [*trie*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). It is  pronounced either /tri:/ or /trai/. However, according to the common spelling rule, "When two vowels go walking, the first one does the talking", the pronunciation is not reasonable. I want to know how to spell this word correctly.

Comment: See the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) article.

Comment: Your question answers itself, doesn't it? _trie_ is spelled _trie_. It's a bit like asking John what his name is.

Comment: The *ie* in *trie* can be pronounced as in *menagerie* and  *beanie*, or it can be pronounced as in *tie* or *pie*. Both pronunciations have adequate precedent in English. Just be glad we don't pronounce it the way *ie* is (sometimes) pronounced in *lingerie*: *tray*.

Answer (score 7):

A *[trie](https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/tree/trie/)* is spelled thusly and sounds like the word *try* or *tree*, but actually comes from the word re**trie**val.

Because the source word's *trie* sounds like *tree*, this can be one valid pronunciation. On another, it is obvious that on its own, *trie* can look like it should be pronounced *try*, especially when it is intended to sound audibly different from *tree* when in verbal discussion.

Answer (score 1):

It is *spelled* "trie."

Since it is a new word, people can pronounce it however they want to. Do you not think the first option is 'reasonable,' since the term trie comes from retrieve?

Do you not think the second option is reasonable in an attempt to make it sound different from the word *tree?*

Welcome to English. We don't have either standardized or reasonable spelling/pronunciation. This ain't Mandarin.

Edit: in other words, few native English speakers are going to pay attention to that 'common spelling rule,' simply because such spelling 'rules' are only descriptions of certain patterns. Outside of that, since the sound system of English does not correspond to the orthography, native speakers have a *variety* of possible spellings and/or pronunciations for any new word that may come along. And the choices we make may not seem reasonable to a non-native speaker...

Comment: If you have sources, please link them. Let your answers be authoritative and authoritatively sourced.

Comment: Mandarin has reasonable spelling/pronunciation? (Both English and Mandarin are totally standardized).

Comment: Mandarin may have reasonable spelling when it's transliterated, but the native script is anything but reasonable.